# Magento 2.3.0 product image cache resizing images

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, product-images, media-images, image-resizing

All my images are 1024X1024 HQ images. When magneto move the imaged to cache folder it resize it and make i get smaller images with white frame all around it (see images "before"). 
I try to fix it by changing the etc/view.xml file but same problom. to fix it i have copy all images from /pub/media/catalog/product/ TO /pub/media/catalog/product/cache/b3b166914d87ce343d4dc5ec5117b502/
same location the images show on . This have fix the problem BUT after 24H images go back to same size with the white frame.

Can you understand what making it ? how it can be that after 1 day the cache images change back again?

Thanks[image: white frame]
[image: after fix]
[image: copy images]

Comment: have you make any cron for image resizing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set image sizes in `view.xml` file inside your theme

Code would be like this:

```
<view xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/view.xsd">
    <media>
        <images module="Magento_Catalog">
            <image id="bundled_product_customization_page" type="thumbnail">
                <width>140</width>
                <height>140</height>
            </image>
            <image id="cart_cross_sell_products" type="thumbnail">
                <width>200</width>
                <height>248</height>
            </image>
            <image id="cart_page_product_thumbnail" type="small_image">
                <width>165</width>
                <height>165</height>
            </image>
            ........
        </images>
    </media>
    ......
</view>
```

Make sure your all images sizes are 1:1 ratio, as your main image proportion is 1:1 in ratio, than after frontend deployment it should work

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Comment: Hi,i try it and its not working for me.

Comment: Hi,i try it and its not working for me.

Comment: Which file did you edit? I have applied this solution before and it always works

Comment: this solution (tried to update the etc/view.xml ) i have try over and over again i have try to tried to update the etc/view.xml with different image size and could not solve the issue. I see that the extension of Fotorama used in the product details page can this extension resize the image and white background issue?

Comment: search with the keyword keepFrame=false, it will remove white space despite of size and ratio